# PHP Getting data from another site

Tags: php, html, web-services, cookies, web

I've got a problem I don't really know how to solve.

What I want to accomplish is to go to an external site and retrieve a webpage, then parse the site and get some values of it. The only problem is that the site requires a login to work.

How I think i might solve it:

1. Promt user for their credentials to the site
2. Using PHP somehow log the user in on the site and store the session cookie
3. later on use that cookie while accessing another page with that cookie
4. Do htmlscraping and interpret it
5. Present data to user

The steps I'm not quite sure how to do is step 2 and 3, how might I do this using PHP? Is it even possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After you got the user credentials you can do something like this:

```
//Assuming $_POST['user'] and $_POST['pass'] hold the credentials for the remote site:

//insert the URL the login form on the remote page posts to
$url = "http://www.example.com/login/" 

//Define your cookie file path. Must be accessable/writable by the webserver
$cookie_file_path = "/path/for/storing/the/cookies/mycookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Note: You'll have to check the remote form for it's field names and set user and password to the input field names

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "user=$_POST['user']&password=$_POST['pass']");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);

$return = curl_exec($ch);

print_r $return;
```

Later you just have to send you Cookiefile and Cookiejar with the curl GET Requests.

Have a look at the [PHP examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ebay_login.html) from the official cURL page.